# Wifi manager app to show usage per access point

Tags: android

Is there any app available on Google Play Store which does following task:

I have two WiFi router (with fixed SSID) connections, one at home and other at office.

I want data usage details for both connections separately, so that I can track usage at each place. Right now default data usage in settings shows overall data usage of *all* WiFi connections.

**Requirements:**

- Android app
- available on *Google Play Store*
- collects data usage statistics
- shows statistics for each configured WiFi network separately

Comment: If, after a reasonable time, you can't find an answer you are happy with, ping me (@me). This sounds like a nice side project.

Comment: Thanks, so you are not aware of any such app. Or is it no apps available?

Comment: Try: *my data manager* it count for multiple SIM ( no option though).  May be wifi too.